# How to make password with special character using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to enter my password with special characters

capital letter, small letter, number and minimum 8 characters

I have this validator array and its need to also display message that password needs to be one capital , one small and minimum 8 characters.

```
public function admin_credential_rules(array $data){
    $messages = [
        'new_password.required' => "Zdejte novÃ© heslo.",
        'password.required' => "Zadejte souÄasnÃ© heslo.",
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'password' => 'required',
        'new_password' => 'required'
    ], $messages);

    return $validator;
}
```

how i can implement that.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'password' => 'required|
               min:8|
               regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/|
               confirmed',
```

This will check for the one capital, one small letter, one numeric digit and one special character as well. Minimum number of character is 8. Hope it works

```
^ asserts position at start of the string
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Positive Lookahead (?=.{3,})
Assert that the Regex below matches
.{3,} matches any character (except for line terminators)
{3,} Quantifier — Matches between 3 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Positive Lookahead (?=.*[a-zA-Z])
Assert that the Regex below matches
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Match a single character present in the list below [a-zA-Z]
a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)
Positive Lookahead (?=.*[0-9])
Assert that the Regex below matches
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Match a single character present in the list below [0-9]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)
Positive Lookahead (?=.*[\d\X])
Assert that the Regex below matches
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Match a single character present in the list below [\d\X]
\d matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
\X matches the character X literally (case sensitive)
Positive Lookahead (?=.*[!$#%])
Assert that the Regex below matches
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Match a single character present in the list below [!$#%]
.* matches any character (except for line terminators)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)


          public function admin_credential_rules(array $data){
    $messages = [
        'new_password.required' => "Zdejte novÃ© heslo.",
        'password.required' => "Zadejte souÄasnÃ© heslo.",
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'password' => 'required|min:8|regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/|confirmed',
        'new_password' => 'required|min:8|regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/|confirmed',
    ], $messages);

    return $validator;
}
```

Comment: do i need to enter this patterin in new_password?

Comment: that depends if it is a password change code then yes

Comment: this is a general idea how you can do validation, you can apply it any one you want and keep that confirm field if you are using confirm password field otherwise there is no need of it

Comment: Did you write the regex? It does more than what your statement says. I think your statement's regex would be `^.*(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$` Assuming the OP only considers `!$#%` special characters.

Comment: yes it is a passsord change code

Comment: @Exterminator there is 3 field password , new password and password_confirmation   'password' is for new password and new_password is for password_confirmation

Comment: That's upto you if you want to validate the old password or not.

Comment: please see my edit code it says password is invalid format and password confirmation does not match

Comment: instead of password use `old_password` for old password and remove confirm option from that and instead of `new_password` use `password` and keep it the same way